# AWS-Amplify v6 Clock Sync Issue After Upgrading Packages and Manual Clock Changes

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I updated `aws-amplify` from `^4.1.0` to `^6.0.13` and `amazon-cognito-identity-js` from `^4.3.2` to `^6.3.7`, respectively. Post-upgrade, whenever I tweak my machine's clock, request syncing goes haywire, not aligning properly with server time—a throwback issue from our project's early days, previously fixed by:

```
const syncAWSClock = async () => {
    const authenticatedUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({bypassCache: true});
    const clockDrift = _get(authenticatedUser, 'signInUserSession.clockDrift', 0);
    const clockOffset = -(clockDrift * 1000);
    DateUtils.setClockOffset(clockOffset);
};
```

This fix was baked into our API request handler. But with the new aws-amplify version, this workaround became inaccessible, seemingly replaced by an automatic handler. Oddly, I noticed the correct timeDrift now gets stored in cookies.
[the clockdrift stored correct in the cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPWPA.png)

i tried to fix it by doing this option:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
AWS.config.update({ 
   correctClockSkew: true,
   systemClockOffset: 3603033
})
```

but it not worked aldo i see that it updated right keys in the AWS.config file.

Does somebody had this issue?

This is how the config file looked like before the upgrade:

```
Amplify.configure({
        Auth: {
            mandatorySignIn: true,
            region: "region",
            userPoolId: "userPoolId",
            identityPoolId: "identityPoolId",
            userPoolWebClientId: "userPoolWebClientId",
            cookieStorage: {
                domain: window.location.hostname,
                secure: true,
                path: '/',
                expires: 7,
            },
            oauth: {
                domain: domainName,
                scope: ['email', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin', 'openid', 'profile'],
                redirectSignIn: publicUrl.origin,
                redirectSignOut: publicUrl.origin,
                responseType: 'code',
            },
        },
        Storage: {
            region: _get(s3Config, 'Region'),
            bucket: _get(s3Config, 'Bucket'),
           identityPoolId: "identityPoolId",
        },
        API: {
            endpoints: [
                {
                    name: 'myapi',
                    endpoint: "endpoint",
                    region: "region"
                },
            ],
            webSocket: "webSocket"
        },
    })
```

And this is how it looks like after the upgrade:

```
Amplify.configure({
        Auth: {
            mandatorySignIn: true,
            userPoolWebClientId: "userPoolWebClientId",
            region: "region",
            Cognito: {
                identityPoolId: "identityPoolId",
                userPoolClientId: "userPoolClientId",
                userPoolId: "userPoolId",
                loginWith: {
                    oauth: {
                        domain: domainName,
                        scopes: ['openid email profile aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
                        redirectSignIn: [publicUrl.origin],
                        redirectSignOut: [publicUrl.origin],
                        responseType: 'code',
                    },
                    username: 'true',
                },
            },
        },
        Storage: {
            S3: {
                bucket: _get(s3Config, 'Bucket'),
                region: _get(s3Config, 'Region'),
            },
        },
        API: {
            REST: {
                myapi: {
                    endpoint: "endpoint",
                    region: "region",
                },
            },
        },
    });

cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider.setKeyValueStorage(new CookieStorage({
        domain: window.location.hostname,
        secure: true,
        path: '/',
        expires: 7,
    }));
```

updated aws-amplify from ^4.1.0 to ^6.0.13 and the flow break is the time in the machine not automaticlly synced

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and traced it to a bug in amplify related to a aws-sdk v2 => v3 breaking change. The open issue is here:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/13192

The basic problem is that in
core/src/clients/middleware/retry/defaultRetryDecider.ts#L19

```
const errorCode = parsedError?.code;
```

should be

```
const errorCode = parsedError?.name;
```

(`code` changing to `name` was a aws sdk change as you probably ran into)

This causes the API call to *not* retry because it does not detect the clock error.

Hopefully they fix quickly, but we're looking at a manual patch in our build flow in the meantime as a workaround.

### Update on workaround:

We were able to patch amplify pretty easily using this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

It runs as a post-install script and can patch an npm package without having to fork

I just followed the setup instructions, pointed it to package @aws-amplify/core and made the change in my first reply to these two files:

node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/dist/cjs/clients/middleware/retry/defaultRetryDecider.js

and

node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/dist/esm/clients/middleware/retry/defaultRetryDecider.mjs